# Get form fields from custom Taglib

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags, taglib

I've written a reusable custom taglib and now there is a requirement that we need to get the form field names from within the taglib class. Currently I pass them as a csv parameter;
The form could be anywhere inside the page where the custom taglib is defined(Could be also an include jsp).

**E.G**

```
<custom:myTagLib formFields="fileda,fieldb,fieldc"/>


<form ...id="formA">

<input type="text" name="fielda"/>
<input type="hidden" name="fieldb"/>
<input type="text" name="fieldc"/>

</form>
```

The csv becomes too big and easily prone to errors/developers missing form fields etc when you have a form with too many fields.

**Requirement or nice to have:**

In the myTagLib:

```
List<String> formElements = getMeAllFormElements("formA")
```

Is this possible at all/HAs anybody done this sort of thing? May be using the Webcontainer api's you could probably, but I am loking for a generic solution.

**Update**

The Response object will have CoyoteResponse(if using tomcat or something similar for other containers) which gets your html rendered output(Which we can use to parse elements out using jsoup etc). But again using that would make the code so much coupled with your container! So leaving this question as it is!

Comment: Do you need attribute names in jsp to render the output? Would it be suitable for you to pass form's attribute iteration to browser via javascript?

Comment: @LeosLiterak - The Taglibs are rendered before the page is loaded. So JS in picture is out of scope. I need to get the form fields while the page is rendered. I know it's very unlikely to be possible, but just checking.

Comment: I know that, but I was just checking if you really need it. I can only imagine that if form definition was special tag as well than you could be able to extract it. Similar to JSF page model.

Comment: No js won't work at all. I need the form element names inside the taglib dynamically, I mean I should be able to get them during runtime. The solution I am putting forward is to parse the physical jsp file.

Comment: my second reply was not about js at all

Comment: If I don't need it I won't be mad enough to waste my/others time asking this question here. Saying that the heading says - **Requirement or nice to have:** So I can leave without this feature but was really checking if this possible knowing almost certain there isn't a direct solution. The Response object will have CoyoteResponse(if using tomcat) which gets your html rendered output but again using that would make the code so coupled!

Comment: @LeosLiterak - I added an update on the question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnann.html for tag cooperation. I would try to define my custom form / input tags and their handler would besides rendering HTML store input id into some map stored as page attribute. Then your tag could extract it from this shared page attribute.

Comment: @LeosLiterak - Not sure if you understood the situation correctly. Tag handlers are able to store only the attributes for that respective tags or it's child/parent tags. We are talking about form and elements which are no where related to the custom tags and are sometimes inside another include file. Beside the tags which I have written are complicated tags which contains iterator/body tags and lots child tags. As I put my update, there isn't a  solution. Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: well, you need some jsp preprocessor before it gets compiled and annotate resulting servlet class with defined form elements.

Comment: You're thinking backwards.  Rather than getting the form elements in JSP, you are building them.  You should start with an array or list and build from it, rather than literally type out the form and then try to get an array or list.

Comment: @developerwjk - Sadly nobody is getting what I am trying to do.